# create a folder in a networked system from another system

Tags: vb.net

i want to save a jpeg file from one system to another system which is connected through network.its in a windows application.my target system's name is "abc".how can i do this ?if anyone knows please help me.thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided you have the sufficient permissions you can do this:

```
System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory("\\share\NewFolder")
```

Answer (score 0):

any file function should also work on network environment if you have sufficient permissions

```
Imports System.IO
Directory.CreateDirectory("\\\\192.168.0.1\\share\\dir")
```